# Wireshark captures packet but JAVA application do not capture

Tags: java, networking, udp, wireshark

I am working on a application on MEGACO protocol on Controller side. I am sending MEGACO messages to the Media Gateway via UDP prptocol. And the Media gateway is answering the requests. When I run wireshark with specified port and IP filter wireshark shows all the captured MEGACO packets. But in my application (written in JAVA) some of the packets are not reaching. More specifically saying to my application only Transaction Reply and Transaction Reply Acknowledgement (Reference: RFC 3015) messages are not reaching.

I have tried a lot of permutations and combinations. Even I have allocated new Datagram Packet and buffer space for each receiving messages as test. But no result. My code for the udp receiver is following.

```
while (running) {
        //do work here
        try {
            byte[] dpBuffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
            DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(dpBuffer, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
            this.socket.receive(dp);
            byte[] temp = new byte[dp.getLength()];
            System.arraycopy(dp.getData(), 0, temp, 0, dp.getLength());
            System.out.println("Read data");
            for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
            {
                System.out.print((char)(temp[i]));
            }
            ByteArrayUtil msg = new ByteArrayUtil(temp, dp.getLength());
            msgParser.parseMsg(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Megaco Reader Failed to read Packet due to :" ,e);
        }
    }
```

Any help??

Comment: I would recheck those Wireshark captures for the source and destination ports of those datagrams.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. After your comment I have just checked the port field in the packets. And found that, those  packets which are not being received by the JAVA program has destination port of 60800. but the rest of the packets which are received by both Wireshark and JAVA program have port of 2944. But I can't understand  this!!! I am setting filter in wireshark as  "udp.port == 2944 && ip.src == IP address" But how the packets field in these packets turn into 60800 !!!!

Comment: "udp.port == 2944" will look for the port number in both destination and source ports. Remember, UDP packets contain 2 port numbers, one applicable to each system. Have a second look and you'll find 2944 in one of them.

Comment: Thanks everyone for commenting. It was my fault. I misunderstood some lines of the protocol and I was not checking the two port. i was just using udp.port filter. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to know. You may wish to answer your own question, so you can help people who made the same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THanks E_net4.

As I have mentioned in my comment, I was using wrong filter in wireshark. in wireshark if you use only

```
"udp.port == x"
```

as the filter it will filter those packets having either source or destination port x. To filter those packets that have either source port == x or destination port ==x, you should use  udp.srcport == x and udp.destport==xrespectively. 
Thanks everyone.